# How can I get this sticky footer working?

Tags: css, padding, sticky-footer, sticky, jsbin

I've applied the CSS sticky footer tutorial that I got from [here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) on my website, but for some reason I can't get it to work?

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eyoric/5/edit)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the top margin from #body and replace it with padding:

```
#body {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 170px;
}
```

add 100% height to html (not only body):

```
html, body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Full JSBin solution](http://jsbin.com/eyoric/9/edit) and [preview](http://jsbin.com/eyoric/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply the correct `#footer` id in your HTML code?

```
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, can't see that I haven't?

Comment: i saw your code ...
i suggest start over from the Warpper DIV with the 2 nested main and footer, the is most probably just a naming error.

Comment: you're trying to add ... something .. witch should have been added @ the start of project ... this is most probably why it want work ... you lost oversight.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the issue? As far as I can see, I have a `#wrapper | #nav | #body | #footer` ??

Comment: use the clean sticky code from the tutorial in a fresh start ...  just start with the WRAP div and the 2 ntested main and footer div tag, that should probably work right away, than add your stuf carefully ... 1 by 1 instead of pasting everying .... add 1 thing @ a time and debug stuff before shit happens

Answer (score 0):

I can not immediatly see what is wrong with your code (it is a lot of css, and you use strange tags like center). I swear by this version of the sticky footer however: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Works fine for me and is very much legacy/cross browser compatible. Perhaps this is an option for you...

Comment: I've tried RyanFait's sticky footer option, but for some reason it just doubles the height of my footer and doesn't make it sticky either?

Comment: I think you must be doing something wrong then, as it has always worked for me. Are you sure you are not applying any additional margins/padings on your wrapper or footer?